# Call Endpoint of one service from another in same kubernetes cluster using service name

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, kubectl, resttemplate

I have Two services Runing on kubernetes cluster. say order service and helath service.
i need to call Actuator metrics endpoint of order service from health service using rest Template.

Here i need to use service name of the order service and not the IP.
I alreday have service name nad name space.

I use below code to call the endpoint,

```
String url ="http://<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<port>/actuator/metrics/<metricName>";
ActuatorMetricsResponse response = this.restTemplate.getForObject(url, ActuatorMetricsResponse.class);
```

Is it ok and do i need to use port here?
Do i need to add aditional properties in application.properties?
How it is resolve IP from this url here?

Comment: URL is correct. Also, your app doesn't need to resolve IP address by itself as CoreDNS will do that for you.

Comment: Do i need additional properties, because this gives me 404 error. what cloud be the issue?

Comment: Error 404 usually means that requested resource doesn't exist anymore. Perhaps
your `metricName` resource doesn't exist or your endpoint isn't correct. Double check it by port-forwarding the service to local machine & call it with `curl`.